# Is it possible to use ExpandoObject to create run-time properties?

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

Normally, we can create properties like this,

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Price = 45k;
expando.Value = "Good";
```

In my case, I won't know the properties such as "Price" or "Value" until runtime. How, can I create such dynamic properties. Something like,

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando[properties[0]] = 45k;
expando[properties[1]] = "Good";
expando[properties[2]] = "Red";
expando[properties[3]] = 8;
```

Anyway to achieve this kind of behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding unknown (at design time) properties to an ExpandoObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974008/adding-unknown-at-design-time-properties-to-an-expandoobject)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use the fact that it implements `IDictionary<string, Object>`:

```
IDictionary<string, Object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando[properties[0]] = 45;
expando[properties[1]] = "Good";
expando[properties[2]] = "Red";
expando[properties[3]] = 8;

dynamic d = expando;
// Now use the properties as normal
```

On the other hand, if you don't know the properties until execution time, what's actually going to consume them? It *may* still make sense to use `ExpandoObject` - but equally it *may* make sense to use `Dictionary<string, object>` to start with.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. 

I have AdomdDataReader object. Since, no Grid controls support AdomdData objects to be bound as ItemsSource, I would like to generate a lighter enumerable source from the ADR. For that I was looking into dynamics, since most of the grid controls supports dynamic binding. Thanks again.

Comment: +1, especially for pointing out that it may be stupid to use ExpandoObject in this case. Currently refactoring my code to use a plain Dictionary instead. :)