# Linq anonymous properties over parameter

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Is it possible select an anonymous type via list of properties as parameter. The method should look like:

```
public void TestLinq(List<"Properties"> properties, List<Data> data)
{
    var dat = from d in data select new { properties };
}
```

I know the description sounds clumsy but I hope I get some help.

It would be important to know the term I have to look for this topic.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet where you actually call `ExportCsv`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dynamic LINQ query library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) ([download the sample](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx)) to create the list of properties in your projection, like so:

```
public dynamic TestLinq(IEnumerable<Data> data, IEnumerable<string> properties)
{
    // Validate parameters.
    if (properties == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("properties");
    if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

    // Construct the field list.
    var fields = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string p in properties) fields.AppendFormat("{0},", property);

    // Throw an exception if there are no items.
    if (fields.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException(
        "The properties enumeration contains no elements.", "properties");

    // Remove the last comma.
    fields.Length--;

    // Select the items and return.  Create the
    // projection here.
    return data.Select("new(" + fields + ")");
}
```

Note that the return type is of type [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx), so you'll have no compile-time checking, and unless you're [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), you probably won't have much knowledge of the fields.

You *might* be better off creating strong types for this, depending on your needs (if this is based on user-input, then you can't obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, this is based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5310828/491950

```
List<string> properties = new List<string>() { {"ResultPrefix"}, {"ProfileResult"}};

foreach (dynamic d in ListProperties(properties, cellValues))
{
     Console.WriteLine(d.ResultPrefix);
}


public static List<dynamic> ListProperties(List<string> properties, List<ChemistryResult> chemistryResults)
{
    List<dynamic> output = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (ChemistryResult chemistryResult in chemistryResults)
    {
        IDictionary<string, Object> result = new ExpandoObject();

        foreach (string property in properties)
        {
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(ChemistryResult).GetProperty(property);

            result[property] = propertyInfo.GetValue(chemistryResult);
        }

        output.Add(result);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: I think it might be even easier than this.  The original question (look at the edits), says the OP wants to make a CSV.  So instead of making a dynamic List of Dictionaries, you can just make a List of strings.  Too bad OP edited away the part that makes the question more obvious.

Comment: @cadrell0 That requirement is gone, that was in a [previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13707999/1) but was removed before any answers showed up.

Comment: I was referring to @cadrell0 and him asking about making a CSV.  Everyone's answer is based on the current revision.  Also, the question is not mine.  I answered the question myself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use anonymous types in a method signature.  It cannot be used as a parameter or the  return type.

What you could do, is declare the parameter as [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but dynamic can get really sticky, so I recommend avoiding it.  You could have a `List<dynamic>` parameter, then you will be able to access members of the type, but you will not get type checking at compile time.

Another option it to use [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) or [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx).  Using either of these will allow you to access the members of the collection without knowing the type.  This is safer, as you have all of your compile time checks, but will not allow you to access members or the anonymous type.

But really, you should just convert your anonymous type into a real class so you can make your life easier.

Comment: If the property list is based on user-input, there's no way to know what the projection should be.  Granted, they should just select all properties from `Data`, but a dynamic projection isn't so far outside the realm of possibility.

Comment: @casperOne I didn't get the impression that OP is trying to do some form of projects based on the question, but if that is the case, your solution is certainly the way to go.

Comment: That, or too lazy to not duck type, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the confusion. The outcome should be a csv that's right. The user should be able to define the order of the columns. But for me it was very difficult to formulate a good question. I am looking for a solution with expresisons not with reflection. My Idea was to generate a List of anonymous objects (with the right order) and out of them I wanted to create the csv. So I know the following  is working:

```
public void Get(List<Value> data,Expression<Func<Value, T>> converter)
{
    var dat = from d in data
     select
         new
         {
               converter
         };
}
```

Is it possible to safe the Expression> converter in a property and combine many of them to one? So I would get the corret order