# Is it possible to create properties on the fly, with a .NET dynamic object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I'm trying to create a some Json in my MVC app and I only want to include the properties from my source object, if it has some properties values, set.

eg.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Aaaa { get; set; }
    public string Bbbb { get; set; }
    public int? Ccccc { get; set; }
    public Lol Dddd { get; set; }
}
```

`// Example Outputs.`

1. Aaaa and Ccccc have values only:
   `return Json(new { Aaaa = source.Aaaa, Cccc = source.Ccccc.Value };`
2. Dddd only has been set.
   `return Json(new { Dddd = source.Dddd }`

See how i was trying to create an anonymous object on the fly. Well, I can do that because in this contrite example, I know what was set. But when it comes to real code, I would have to do 'figure out' what was really set and then dynamically return that.

The idea is based upon [Stack Exchange's Api Wrapper](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) .. where they have some optional values that they return via json, if they are set.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974008/adding-unknown-at-design-time-properties-to-an-expandoobject

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx), an example with xml is given [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx)

eg.

```
dynamic contact = new ExpandoObject();
contact.Name = "Patrick Hines";
contact.Phone = "206-555-0144";
... etc ...
```

Comment: henrik, looked thro that expandoobject() stuff a while back. i can't help but agree with 'bob's' observations on it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx#10003637