# Add property to ExpandoObject with the same name as a string

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

Is there a way to add a property to an ExpandoObject with the same name as a string value?

For example, if I have:

```
string propName = "ProductNumber";
dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
```

I can create the property ProductNumber like:

```
obj.ProductNumber = 123;
```

But, can I create the property `obj.ProductNumber` based on the string `propName`?  So, if I don't know what the name of the property will be in advanced, I can create it based on this input. If this is not possible with ExpandoObject, any other areas of C# I should look into?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding unknown (at design time) properties to an ExpandoObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974008/adding-unknown-at-design-time-properties-to-an-expandoobject)

Comment: Practical use of the above found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974008/adding-unknown-at-design-time-properties-to-an-expandoobject

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ExpandoObject implements `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
((IDictionary<string, object>)obj)[propName] = propValue
```

I don't know off the top of my head whether you can use the indexer syntax with a `dynamic` reference (i.e., without the cast), but you can certainly try it and find out.

Comment: you can't index an ExpandoObject as you've done in your first example

Comment: Second example is good.  First example gives `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'`

Comment: @Paul thanks -- I had forgotten that the indexer is an explicit interface implementation.  Answer edited.

Comment: @VBRonPaulFan yes, I had forgotten that the interface implementation is explicit.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: man, i am so glad i found this post. i was about to implement some object off of DynamicObject from some other tutorials just to get this ability. life and time saver thanks!! :D

Answer (score 20):

Cast the `ExpandoObject` to an `IDictionary<string,object>` to do this:

```
string propName = "ProductNumber";
dynamic obj = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
var dict = (IDictionary<string,object>)obj;
dict[propName] = 123;
```

Comment: +1 for at least mentioning that `ExpandoObject` is `IDictionary<string,object>` underneath. [See docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)