# How to turn a list of strings into an anonymous type with a property per character

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

Suppose I have a `List<string>`, where each string is of the same length. This length is not know in advance, and can only be determined by checking the Length property of the string (say the first one, as they are all the same length) at run time.

What I would like is to end up with a collection of anonymous objects, each of which has properties C1, C2, etc, one for each character.

So, if the first string in the List were "abcd" then the first anonymous object in the resultant list would be...

```
{
  C1 = "a",
  C2 = "b",
  C3 = "c",
  C4 = "d"
}
```

Is this possible? I've been struggling with dynamics and ExpandoObjects, but haven't managed to make either of them work. The main problem seems to be not knowing the property names in advance.

I tried doing things like (in a loop)...

```
d["C" + i] = str.[j];
```

...but this doesn't work as it thinks I'm trying to use array indexing. I get a run-time exception of "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'"

Can this be done?

Comment: I wonder how you are going to consume such objects? And what about "abba" string?

Comment: Consuming isn't an issue, as this is to be passed to a WPF grid which will bind the properties to columns that we add on the fly. Duplicate chars aren't an issue either, as the order of chars in the string is significant. Didn't think that bit was relevant, so didn't mention it in the question

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel: Maybe you can take a peek at the `TypeBuilder` utility: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx With that, you could iterate on the input and generate mapped properties and assign values. Regarding Expando, you might be able to insert properties/data into it like an indexer if you cast it to a dictionary first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778625/1269654 EDIT: Perhaps a slightly better answer for expando: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10048479/1269654

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at casting the `ExpandoObject` to a `Dictionary`, but the problem is that I don't know what to do with the `object` as I only know the number of properties at run time. I'll take a look at the `TypeBuilder`

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel: Wouldn't it be very similar to your sample code? `for(int i = 1; i <= myString.Length; i++) ((IDictionary<string, object>)d)["C" + i] = myString[i - 1];`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Ah, I didn't get that! When I cast the `ExpandoObject` to `IDictionary<String, object>` I can then use the square brackets to add properties on the fly. Shame I can't mark a comment as the answer, although it would need some sample code to qualify. Thanks very much

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel: Sergey's posted answer is an equivalent/better. Mark his as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can treat `ExpandoObject` as a dictionary with property names as keys, and values as property values. With this simple extension method you can create an ExpandoObject and populate it with properties generated from source string:

```
public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this string s)
{
    var obj = new ExpandoObject();
    var dictionary = obj as IDictionary<string, object>;       
    var properties = s.Distinct().Select((ch, i) => new { Name = $"C{i+1}", Value = ch });

    foreach (var property in properties)
        dictionary.Add(property.Name, property.Value);

    return obj;
}
```

Usage:

```
var source = new List<string> { "bob", "john" };
var result = source.Select(s => s.ToExpando());
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "C1": "b",
    "C2": "o"
    // NOTE: If C3 = "b" is required here, than remove Distinct() in extension method
  },
  {
    "C1": "j",
    "C2": "o",
    "C3": "h",
    "C4": "n"
  }
]
```

Comment: I think the `Distinct()` is probably not part of OP's intent. As you mentioned, "abba" could just map to: `C1=a, C2=b, C3=b, C4=a` and I don't think this would cause issues. EDIT: Otherwise, I think this satisfies the request.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair yep, if duplicated values are ok, then `Disctinct()` should be removed here. Probably I didn't get correctly OP answer to my comment

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I thought I had answered it actually, I said that the order of the characters is significant, so I know what the first char represents, and don't care if it happens to be the same char as one in a different position. Either way, your code looks great thanks. I'm just playing around with it, as I think I can actually drop the `ExpandoObject` and deal directly with objects of type `Dictionary<String, dynamic>`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy As I thought, this can be simplified. You can just create a `Dictionary<String, dynamic>` and add properties to that. No need for an `ExpandoObject` at all. Thanks again