# C# DynamicObject dynamic properties

Tags: c#, dynamicobject

Assuming I cannot use an ExpandoObject and have to roll my own like so :-

```
class MyObject : DynamicObject {
    dictionary<string, object> _properties = dictionary<string, object>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

        return _properties.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
        _properties[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;

        return true;
    }
}
```

and further down the class hierarchy I have

```
class MyNewObject : MyObject {
    public string Name {
        get {
            // do some funky stuff
        }
        set {
            // ditto
        }
    }
}
```

which is quite nice as now I can do the follow :-

```
dynamic o = MyNewObject();

o.Age = 87;     // dynamic property, handled by TrySetMember in MyObject
o.Name = "Sam"; // non dynamic property, handled by the setter defined in MyNewObject
```

But the above assumes I know the properties (e.g. Age, Name) at compile time.

Suppose I don't know what they will be until run time.

How can I change the above to support properties I will only know at run time?

Basically I think I am asking is how I can call the code that calls TrySetMember directly so that it will either create a new property or use a getter/setter if one has been defined.

**Final Solution as follows :-**

```
using System.Dynamic;
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class MyObject : DynamicObject {
    Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object GetMember(string propName) {
        var binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
              propName, this.GetType(),
              new List<CSharpArgumentInfo>{
                       CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)});
        var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object>>.Create(binder);

        return callsite.Target(callsite, this);
    }

    public void SetMember(string propName, object val) {
        var binder = Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
               propName, this.GetType(),
               new List<CSharpArgumentInfo>{
                       CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
                       CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)});
        var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(binder);

        callsite.Target(callsite, this, val);
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();

        return _properties.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
        _properties[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you not implement `IDictionary<string, object>` as well? [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974008/adding-unknown-at-design-time-properties-to-an-expandoobject)

Comment: Thanks a ton for providing a non-library based solution!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although the c# compiler is translating dynamic keyword usage to invocation with the dlr using a string name, those Apis are difficult to use directly without the compilers help. The open source framework [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey) (available through nuget as a PCL library) encapsulates the dlr API, to make it easy so that you can just call [Impromptu.InvokeSet(target, name, value)](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic-invokesetobject-target-string_or_invokemembername-name-object-value).

```
using Dynamitey;
...

dynamic o = MyNewObject();

Dynamic.InvokeSet(o,"Age" ,87); 
Dynamic.InvokeSet(o,"Names" ,"Sam");
```

Getters and Setters are the least complicated to use the actual Microsoft API directly, so if you don't want to use the 3rd party framework going to the [source](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/blob/master/Dynamitey/Internal/Optimization/InvokeHelper-Regular.cs#L472) is an option too.

```
using Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
...

  dynamic o = MyNewObject();
  var binder = Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
                   "Age",
                   typeof(object),
                   new List<CSharpArgumentInfo>{
                           CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
                           CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
                                               });

  var callsite = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(binder);

  callsite.Target(callsite,o,87);

  var binder2 =Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
                   "Name",
                   typeof(object),
                   new List<CSharpArgumentInfo>{
                           CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
                           CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)
                                               });
  var callsite2 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(binder2);

  callsite2.Target(callsite2,o,"Sam");
```

No StackOverflow, there is nothing to improve

Comment: cool. using binders works great. unfortunately working at a place that doesn't allow open source or third party libraries.

Answer (score 6):

> But the above assumes I know the properties (e.g. Age, Name) at compile time.
>
> Suppose I don't know what they will be until run time.

Then the dynamic typing in C# 4 doesn't really help you at all, and you might as well just use `Dictionary<string, object>`.

Rather than *assume* that `dynamic` is the answer, I suggest you take a close look at your requirements, and work out what you're really trying to achieve. Once you've got a well-specified set of requirements, it's going to be easier to implement them.

You *may* find that you just need to make `MyObject` also implement `IDictionary<string, object>` like `ExpandoObject` does... although the problem there is that if you want to *derive* other classes from `MyObject` and have their properties exposed via the dictionary too, that's going to be trickier.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I don't really have any real requirements, just playing with the functionality. However I did want a real class in this instance because I wanted the ability to define setters or getters for some properties I know about in advance yet still be able to later dynamically add other unknown properties later.