# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject w/ DynamicObject and TypeCreationConverter

Tags: c#, json.net, dynamicobject

I have a class `EntityBase` that derives from `DynamicObject` without an empty default constructor.

```
// this is not the actual type but a mock to test the behavior with
public class EntityBase : DynamicObject
{
    public string EntityName { get; private set; }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public EntityBase(string entityName)
    {
        this.EntityName = entityName;
    }

    public virtual object this[string fieldname]
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.values.ContainsKey(fieldname))
                return this.values[fieldname];
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.values.ContainsKey(fieldname))
                this.values[fieldname] = value;
            else
                this.values.Add(fieldname, value);          
        }
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return this.values.Keys.ToList();
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = this[binder.Name];
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        this[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

the JSON I'd like to deserialize looks like this:

```
{'Name': 'my first story', 'ToldByUserId': 255 }
```

`EntityBase` has neither the `Name` nor the `ToldByUserId` property. They should be added to the DynamicObject.

If I let `DeserializeObject` create the object like this everything works as expected:

```
var story = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntityBase>(JSON);
```

but since I don't have an empty default constructor and can't change the class I went for a [CustomCreationConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCustomCreationConverter.htm) :

```
public class StoryCreator : CustomCreationConverter<EntityBase>
{
    public override EntityBase Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new EntityBase("Story");
    }
}
```

but

```
var stroy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntityBase>(JSON, new StoryCreator());
```

throws

> Cannot populate JSON object onto type 'DynamicObjectJson.EntityBase'.
>   Path 'Name', line 1, position 8.

It seems that the `DeserializeObject` calls `PopulateObject` on the object that was created by the `CustomCreationConverter`. When I try to do this manually the error stays the same

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(JSON, new EntityBase("Story"));
```

I further assume that `PopulateObject` does not check if the target type derives from `DynamicObject` and therefore does not fall back to `TrySetMember`.

Note that I don't have influence on the `EntityBase` type definition, it's from an external library and cannot be changed.

Any insights would be highly appreciated!

**Edit**: added an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EGOCFU

Comment: Would you be willing to make a parameterless constructor (possibly private and marked with `[JsonCOnstructor]`) and mark `EntityName` with `[JsonProperty]` or `[DataMember]` as shown in [C# How to serialize (JSON, XML) normal properties on a class that inherits from DynamicObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18822121/3744182)?  I believe that should work.

Comment: sadly I don't have influence on the type definition, it's form an external library

Comment: Does `EntityName` have a private setter in the real type you are trying to deserialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have stumbled on a couple of bugs or limitations in Json.NET's support for deserializing dynamic objects (defined as those for which a [`JsonDynamicContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonDynamicContract.htm) is generated):

1. Support for parameterized constructors is not present.  Even if one is marked with `[JsonConstructor]` it will not get used.

   Here the necessary logic to pre-load all the properties seems to be entirely missing from [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateDynamic()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L1751).  Compare with [`JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L2204) which indicates what would be required.

   Since the logic looks fairly elaborate this might be a limitation rather than a bug.  And actually there is [closed issue #47](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/47) about this indicating that it's not implemented:

   > There would be a fair bit of work to add this feature. You are welcome to submit a pull request if you do add it.
2. Json.NET has no ability to populate a preexisting dynamic object.  Unlike for regular objects (those for which a [`JsonObjectContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract.htm) is generated), logic for construction and population is contained entirely in the previously-mentioned `JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateDynamic()`.

   I don't see why this couldn't be implemented with a fairly simple code restructuring.  You might [submit an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) asking for this.  If this were implemented, your `StoryCreator` would work as-is.

In the absence of either #1 or #2, it's possible to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) whose logic is modeled roughly on `JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateDynamic()` which calls a specified creation method then populates both dynamic and non-dynamic properties, like so:

```
public class EntityBaseConverter : ParameterizedDynamicObjectConverterBase<EntityBase>
{
    public override EntityBase CreateObject(JObject jObj, Type objectType, JsonSerializer serializer, ICollection<string> usedParameters)
    {
        var entityName = jObj.GetValue("EntityName", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (entityName != null)
        {
            usedParameters.Add(((JProperty)entityName.Parent).Name);
        }
        var entityNameString = entityName == null ? "" : entityName.ToString();
        if (objectType == typeof(EntityBase))
        {
            return new EntityBase(entityName == null ? "" : entityName.ToString());             
        }
        else
        {
            return (EntityBase)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, new object [] { entityNameString });
        }           
    }
}

public abstract class ParameterizedDynamicObjectConverterBase<T> : JsonConverter where T : DynamicObject
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType); } // Or possibly return objectType == typeof(T);

    public abstract T CreateObject(JObject jObj, Type objectType, JsonSerializer serializer, ICollection<string> usedParameters);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Logic adapted from JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateDynamic()
        // https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs#L1751
        // By James Newton-King https://github.com/JamesNK

        var contract = (JsonDynamicContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        var jObj = JObject.Load(reader);

        var used = new HashSet<string>();
        var obj = CreateObject(jObj, objectType, serializer, used);

        foreach (var jProperty in jObj.Properties())
        {
            var memberName = jProperty.Name;
            if (used.Contains(memberName))
                continue;
            // first attempt to find a settable property, otherwise fall back to a dynamic set without type
            JsonProperty property = contract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(memberName);

            if (property != null && property.Writable && !property.Ignored)
            {
                var propertyValue = jProperty.Value.ToObject(property.PropertyType, serializer);
                property.ValueProvider.SetValue(obj, propertyValue);
            }
            else
            {
                object propertyValue;
                if (jProperty.Value.Type == JTokenType.Null)
                    propertyValue = null;
                else if (jProperty.Value is JValue)
                    // Primitive
                    propertyValue = ((JValue)jProperty.Value).Value;
                else
                    propertyValue = jProperty.Value.ToObject<IDynamicMetaObjectProvider>(serializer);
                // Unfortunately the following is not public!
                // contract.TrySetMember(obj, memberName, propertyValue);
                // So we have to duplicate the logic of what Json.NET has already done.
                CallSiteCache.SetValue(memberName, obj, propertyValue);
            }               
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

internal static class CallSiteCache
{
    // Adapted from the answer to 
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057516/c-sharp-dynamicobject-dynamic-properties
    // by jbtule, https://stackoverflow.com/users/637783/jbtule
    // And also
    // https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member/blob/master/FastMember/CallSiteCache.cs
    // by Marc Gravell, https://github.com/mgravell

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>> setters 
        = new Dictionary<string, CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>>();

    public static void SetValue(string propertyName, object target, object value)
    {
        CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>> site;

        lock (setters)
        {
            if (!setters.TryGetValue(propertyName, out site))
            {
                var binder = Binder.SetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None,
                       propertyName, typeof(CallSiteCache),
                       new List<CSharpArgumentInfo>{
                               CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null),
                               CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null)});
                setters[propertyName] = site = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, object, object>>.Create(binder);
            }
        }

        site.Target(site, target, value);
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new EntityBaseConverter() },
};
var stroy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EntityBase>(JSON, settings);
```

Since it seems like `EntityBase` may be a base class for multiple derived classes, I wrote the converter to work for all derived types of `EntityBase` with the assumption that they all have a parameterized constructor with the same signature.

Note I am taking the `EntityName` from the JSON.  If you would prefer to hardcode it to `"Story"` you could do that, but you should still add the actual name of the `EntityName` property to the `usedParameters` collection to prevent a dynamic property with the same name from getting created.

Sample working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Gf8nz).

Comment: awesome! using the custom converter like you described it works like a charm!
thank you so much for this high quality answer!