# Dynamic Class where properties come from a list/dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, properties

I would like to create a dynamic class doing with the following:

1. I have a dictionary where the keys are integers and the values are strings.

   ```
   Dictionary<int, string> PropertyNames =  new Dictionary<int, string>();
   PropertyNames.Add(2, "PropertyName1");
   PropertyNames.Add(3, "PropertyName2");
   PropertyNames.Add(5, "PropertyName3");
   PropertyNames.Add(7, "PropertyName4");
   PropertyNames.Add(11,"PropertyName5");
   ```
2. I would like to pass this dictionary into a class constructor which builds Properties into the class instance. And suppose I would like to have both get and set functionality for each of these properties. e.g.:

   ```
   MyDynamicClass Props = new MyDynamicClass( PropertyNames );
   Console.WriteLine(Props.PropertyName1);
   Console.WriteLine(Props.PropertyName2);
   Console.WriteLine(Props.PropertyName3);
   Props.PropertyName4 = 13;
   Props.PropertyName5 = new byte[17];
   ```

I am having trouble understanding [DLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx).

Comment: See this article, I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974008/adding-unknown-at-design-time-properties-to-an-expandoobject

Comment: You're basically describing the `ExpandoObject`. Check it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Comment: Oh okay, I think that is straightforward enough.  I never knew about ExpandoObject.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, would anyone know why MSFT decided to name the class ExpandoObject instead of ExpandObject?  It seems like a typo.

Comment: Just FYI, you are discarding almost all compile-time checks and sacrificing performance when you use such types as ExpandoObject or DynamicObject.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy Thank you for letting me know about the performance penalty. This might be a deal breaker for me since I do have timing requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) class seems to be what you want. In fact the documentation shows how to do exactly what you asked. Reproduced here in a stripped down version for brevity:

```
public class DynamicDictionary : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public int Count
    {
        get { return dictionary.Count; }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        dictionary[binder.Name.ToLower()] = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```